# Configure Nginx to have two different URLs, one for the main site and another for the admin dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

i want two diffrent urls http://example.com and http://example.com/admin-dsahboard  when i hit http://example.com/admin-dsahboard i can see the admin-dsahboard panel but in address bar it shows http://example.com ,
/admin-dashboard is missiing so when i reload the page it reload to frontend website

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /path/to/file/;
        index index.html;
    }
    location /admin-dashboard/ {
        root /path/to/file/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin-dashboard/index.html;
    }    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `try_files` is causing the address bar to not be updated. Something simpler should work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/file/;
    index index.html;

    location /admin-dashboard/ {
        root /path/to/admin/;
        # add configuration to control access here   
    }
}
```

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/file;
    index index.html;

    location /admin-dashboard/ {
        root /path/to/admin/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin-dashboard/index.html;
    }
}
tried this but still facing same issue

Comment: do i need to make changes in forntend code

Comment: Try the config I posted without `try_files`.

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mariamraj.com;

    location / {
        root /home/bitnami/frontend/out;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /admin-dashboard/ {
        root /home/bitnami/admin/admin-dashboard;
        index index.html;
    }
}
is this correct

Comment: also for some reason it show error 403 forbidden even though permisssions are correct and files path is also correct

Comment: Try `root /home/bitnami/admin/` in your /admin-dashboard/ location.

Comment: still facing redirection issue

Comment: when i acces example.com/admin-dashboard/ in address bar it show mariamraj.com i can still loggin to dashboard and access categories but when i refresh the page it shows example.com/categoriesnot found,ithink its because when i hit example.com/admin-dashboard/ it shows example.com in address bar so when i refresh it takes me to frontend website thats running on example.com

Comment: At this point I would recommend starting with a bare bones configuration. When that works, build it back incrementally.